# PHP regex to match whole words only, while not counting dashes as whole words

Tags: php, regex

It's easy enough that `/\b(test1|test2|test3)\b/i` will match whole words, it's also matching them when part of a hyphenated word.

I'd like this to match:

```
foo test1 bar
```

But these not to:

```
foo-test1-bar
foo-test2 bar
foo test3-bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookarounds to prevent matching hyphenated words:

```
/(?<!-)\b(test1|test2|test3)\b(?!-)/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO4kR6/1)

Comment: Upvoted - You can simplify that using a class, `test[123]` =)

Comment: Yes sure that can be done but I assumed OP just provided those sample words and actual words might not be all following `test[0-9]` pattern.

Comment: Yes, those aren't my real words. Thanks for the help, regex is slightly less daunting now.